# Make change to multiple (very) similar files in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When targeting a range of API versions I often have to create new versions of my layout files that only differ in a few lines because they make use of attributes that are only available from certain versions on.

For example, I have to duplicate my whole layout file if I want to use the `android:autofillHints` attribute for `EditText`s on API level 26+.

This makes changes very time consuming. If I decide to add a Button or change the size of some spacing I have to adjust all my layout files.

If I have only two files I can use the comparison view (Ctrl + D) to quickly make changes in both files. However, in more complex projects I occasionally have three or four versions of my layout files with only minor differences.

Is there some obvious way to manage that problem that I'm missing? Because otherwise that fancy 'configuration overriding mechanism' seems like a nightmare when developing large apps that target a broad range of Android versions and device configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [android documentation specifies how to reuse/nest layouts](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts)
basically boils down to using

```
<include layout="@layout/layoutToNest"/>
```

to nest layouts
and using merge to avoid respecifying root layouts

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<layoutElementToNest/>  
<layoutElementToNest2/>

</merge>
```

in your xml to facilitate layout reuse and nesting.

also be sure to use [layout optimising techniques](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout) like android lint to ensure that your layouts are optimised

Comment: That should reduce the redundancy. Especially the possibility to override attributes in the `include` tag.

Comment: yup it's great, however it starts getting hard to track without using hierarchy viewer in android in a production app, so please use that as well